# ChatGPT should be incorporated into the site

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chatgpt

ChatGPT is a tool. We should adopt all useful tools. This site is in the best position to do this adoption. I propose that before the question is published the OP gets the opportunity to read the answer from the AI. The OP might already accept this answer. Or they might realize that the question needs refining. Or they might be struck with inspiration and find the answer by themselves based on an incorrect answer from the AI. These are all good outcomes.

Adopting the AI by the site has nothing to do with banning the use of AI to provide answers. These two policies can coexist.

Comment: Or they might waste their time reading and trying a likely completely useless answer. That's bad both for them and for our reputation as a site with high quality answers.

Comment: _We should adopt all useful tools_... Just no. Tools should only be adopted if there's a clear benefit of having it incorporated (instead of having users be able to use it without integration), if it aligns with the purpose of the site, and if it makes business sense (it's free in a trial phase now, plus even free tools cost dev time = money).

Comment: You are probably not aware *how wrong* can the results be. [Prevent SQL injections. In the browser](https://i.imgur.com/c0CaGFO.png). The code and answer are very confidently complete BS. Yes, some answers it gives are decent. But if a person is asking, they probably can't really differentiate. One answer I saw is where it used a language feature *which does not exist*. It was a proposal but ultimately withdrawn in 2015. Yet, it generated an answer confidently stating it's the way to solve a particular problem.

Comment: If we don't adopt this AI or the next we will get replaced, just like how SO replaced Experts Exchange.

Comment: I don't think there's any evidence that not incorporating AI will get us replaced, but even if that happens and we do get replaced by a superior product with AI, then that's the companies problem, not ours. We just get to move to the better product. Experts exchange getting replaced by SO very much was a good thing, imho.

Comment: AI is just a word made for marketing noise. The real word some people like to use is Neural Network, or even [Statistical Learning](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/191197/is-it-ok-to-generate-parts-of-a-research-paper-using-a-large-language-model-such/191214?noredirect=1#comment516040_191214). AI [does not know, does not understand and is in no way intelligent, even if the result sometimes say otherwise](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/191214/165338). Yes, "AI" tools can be useful, but as others better said, this isn't aligning with the focus of SO/SE for high-quality answers

Comment: While OP is composing the answer a list of existing answers is presented to them. How is this list useful to me? I already googled. No clear benefit from my standpoint. So, why do we like this list, and don't like something similar, but also entirely different? OP can ignore the AI answer just as well. But it also might provide genuine help. It may happen.

Comment: The problem is answerers are _not_ using it as a tool.. They are just blindly copying from ai response and pasting

Comment: @Suraj please read my proposal again. I propose that the **server** provides an answer **before** the question is published. You are talking about the current state of affairs. I am talking about the future.

Comment: ChatGPT may return different and contradicting answers when retried multiple times with the same prompt (question). How many times the asker have to retry it? Or well, why does it have to be done on SO?

Comment: @Dialecticus that may seem to be a good idea, but how will the asker know or even SO know the ai response it is showing is in fact correct or optimal solution?

Comment: @VLAZ Hey, it's not SQL injection if you provide an endpoint to execute arbitrary SQL against your database but process parameters separately. Then it's just SQL. So it's technically correct = the best kind of correct unless you don't want your database leaked/erased 

Comment: "We should adopt all useful tools." - You can. You are very free to use the tool BEFORE you dump a question on Stack Overflow, and maybe save yourself the time. This is an alternative to Stack Overflow, not an extension.

Comment: “I propose that before the question is published the OP gets the opportunity to read the answer from the AI.” - No; I have literally read hundreds of answers generated by ChartGPT, and they all have, been incredibly incorrect. ChartGPT in general generates content that isn’t helpful. “If we don't adopt this AI or the next we will get replaced, just like how SO replaced” - We don’t have to adapt this particular AI, given in my experience, the AI generates low quality answers. ChartGPT isn’t even a real AI.

Comment: I'm not gonna bother contesting the closure in either direction, but please don't vote to delete this question. We've had two duplicates today alone. With the banner up and many people repeatedly having this idea, leaving this as a dupe target saves us of having this discussion over and over for when this inevitably shows up again very soon

Comment: The reason why SO is so great is reputation. Users accumulate reputation by producing worthy answers over many years with great attention to detail, a stringent acceptance process and often 1000s of hours of applied knowledge behind great answers.  A high reputation user is almost always right.  OTOH, ChatGPT integration would short-circuit diabolically wrong answers with zero correlation to reputation to the front of the stack, in the user's face. This lack of human QA is a violation of ML technique and SO standards.  Why should we adopt it?  Because it is "AI" and that is cool?

Comment: @Chris, it seems to me that you, as some others, did not read my proposal carefully. I proposed that the SO itself offers a suggestion from ChatGPT BEFORE the OP publishes the question. We have these suggestions already, and they are mostly useless to me. Again, BEFORE the OP publishes the question. Suggestion offered by SO itself.

Comment: @Dialecticus and that is exactly what I am addressing. The user's face is presented with an unfiltered attempt at an answer by a user (ChatGPT) that is almost always wrong at the top of the stack -- it is the first answer they see after touching SO with their question.  This "short circuits" the reputation driven Q-and-A process with diabolically incorrect answers that have no correlation to long term reputation, as I have stated.

Comment: Current suggestions that are presented to my face are already useless. I have no use of Q-and-A process, if I am presented with something useless. those suggestions could be useful to somebody else. Answers from ChatGPT also could be useful. I use it in my work, trying there when I get nothing from Google & SO. And sometimes it is useful, where Google & SO were not.

Comment: Presenting users who are having trouble interpreting code with an answer that likely *looks* correct but could be wrong/dangerous without an opportunity for an expert to review said answer is dangerous. It can reinforce bad practices, suggest vulnerabilities, create an X/Y situation, etc

Comment: @Dialecticus all of those answers, even if they are "useless", have nonetheless been produced via the natural process of asking an SO question and accepting and upvoting answers that actually worked.  That is a scientific process with high human-in-the-loop quality reassurances and reproducible results which is now getting short circuited by random, plausible and completely wrong content that is subject to zero review.

Comment: Fine, we can have humans in the loop. Let ChatGPT offers only already available answers from SE sites. The AI is better at recognizing what the OP wants to say than SO search engine, that only looks tries to match words, with sometimes rather comical effects. AI can even say something like "it is unclear what you're trying to do, could you please add more context". This would also help a lot.

Comment: @Dialecticus so what you want is a better search engine.  That is a fundamentally different problem and solution set than ChatGPT seeks to solve.

Comment: ChatGPT is that already. Google announced their take will come online in a few weeks.

Comment: @Dialecticus So what you are proposing is to use ChatGPT to search regular stack overflow answers and provide a better list of potential duplicates and related questions, **rather than** suggesting we use ChatGPT to generate an answer?  I don't **think** that is what you were proposing originally, but it **might** be a  healthier way to think about ChatGPT.  Let's agree on that.

Comment: Originally I proposed that ChatGPT generates an answer that would be just one among all other proposed answers (could be more or less useful; it's would be gamble, as it already is). People say it's dangerous. I don't see that danger. Would lives be in danger? What is the worst that could happen? Some could would not work? So, now I am changing my proposal. It is amusing to me that people do not want to adopt something the obviously looks unavoidable anyway.

Comment: @Dialecticus perhaps there can be a "roll the dice" mechanism where ChatGPT does its non-deterministic synth-search thing and produces a different collection of viable duplicates / answers every time.  You can peruse them and satisfy your curiosity before submitting a simple question you are going to delete anyway.  But all Questions and Answers presented are human generated via normal SO operation.  Good compromise?

Comment: @Dialecticus the reason being that there is an implicit proof of work in a human questioner accepting an answer that worked for them when they tried it.  ChatGPT can be trained on all questions and answers, and only provides pointers to the accepted answers to questions semantically similar to the user's, rather than non-deterministically generating garbage.

Comment: We should try all adoption strategies that the community agrees on. IT can get better over time. It can become useful. AI can combine answers. Something like "Try this answers, but beware of dangers described in this answer", or tell the user "please specify the framework, because the answer depends on it". ChatGPT is just a tool that we can use however we want.

Comment: @Dialecticus agree, might want to flag for moderator attention, since this question is important (needed to be asked), you can't delete it now, and it will drive your rep down.

Comment: Downvotes are fine. [Votes on meta do not affect your reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta#:~:text=Votes%20on%20meta%20do%20not,reputation%20to%20participate%20on%20meta.)

Comment: @Dialecticus cool, was looking like you were going to be a martyr.

Comment: Sure, it's a tool. It's absolutely the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: It is... probably the end of the IT as we know. I think this is our big fear and this is the source of our dislike. As the dead convict gets his headband and waits the bullet in the darkness, I think, that is what we collective feel. Maybe... we will see it. It is questionable, what should we do - I am sure, just blocking it and doing nothing is the worst solution. And note: the case is not SO bad. We do not know yet, how will it affect our work, or the work of everyone on the world.

Comment: @Dialecticus That would be okay if it would only express agreement-disagreement. There is nothing bad to have a minority opinion. But, after more than a decade of SO, I believe it express a community bullying and that is already not fine. Very not. However, there is a mostly unsaid majority opinion of this meta site: that having a minority opinion, having many downvoted posts is bad. No it should not and it is a very, very, very bad psychotic direction what can be felt here.

Comment: [It may happen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388492/an-example-of-a-generative-ai-tool-suggesting-better-question-titles) [after all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424638/stack-overflow-will-be-testing-a-title-drafting-assistant-and-we-d-like-your-in).

Comment: Voted reopen, it's not the linked duplicate at all. Downvote all you want, closing is separate.

Comment: If people want answers from ChatGPT, they will go to ChatGPT immediately and not to Stack Overflow. If people come to Stack Overflow, they're looking for high-quality humen-generated answers.

Comment: lol  @VLAZ, I don't see what's wrong with your linked example. Can you please explain? I am a BS victim...

Comment: @IlyaGazman ChatGPT suggests sending the SQL statement to the server which then accepts it and runs it without verifying. The mantra of all server/client applications has always been "Do not trust the client". Sending SQL to be executed on the server directly ignores that and offers literally no security, since any user of the application can send any arbitrary SQL to be executed. For example `DROP TABLE users`. Trying to secure SQL in the client is completely nonsensical.

Comment: @VLAZ oh wow, this an excellent example! it totally got me.

Comment: @Dialecticus gpt is absolute trash at solving even trivial problems and fails to hold a conversation on any subject beyond the most shallow level possible. it's been biased to a degree which makes interrogation of any ethically-adjacent topic impossible. no tin-foil, jus technical disappointment. have you spent any time poking?

Answer (score 63):

I'm gonna throw my non-existing hat in the ring and make an answer, to hopefully clear misunderstanding/confusion (or future ones).

I'm gonna reuse and quote what you said so as to better explain:

> ChatGPT is a tool. We should adopt all useful tools.

Right, I agree it's a tool, and while its usefulness is questionable (eg: it depends on how it is used, the probability of getting a useful answer/output, etc) that does not have anything to do with what SO and SE stand for.

This site thrives for high-quality answers (and questions), by valuable contributors. If you have as others pointed out, to fully check, understand, and retry (eg: using the `Try again` button, or repasting the same input) multiple times until you get what you "seek", this isn't what I call high-quality answer, but more like "throwing something until it sticks".

That's not even the tip of the iceberg in terms of cons, but I'll get to that in a second.

> This site is in the best position to do this adoption. I propose that before the question is published the OP gets the opportunity to read the answer from the AI.

And then what? They'll get confused when a website's main goal is to provide high-quality answers and questions end up giving you a completely wrong one, with no one to blame but a [Statistical Learning algorithm](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/191197/is-it-ok-to-generate-parts-of-a-research-paper-using-a-large-language-model-such/191214?noredirect=1#comment516040_191214)?

Worse case, they repost that as a question while mentioning they don't understand why the "AI" gave them a wrong answer. Multiply that by 10k per day, and that's the kind of thing that will flood the site.

If you have a problem and a "tool" gave you another set of problems that you don't even know how to solve, then I think your main problem is depending on the "tool" in the first place.

> OP might already accept this answer. Or they might realize that the question needs refining. Or they might be struck with inspiration and find the answer by themselves based on incorrect answer from AI. These are all good outcomes.

Having inspiration is fine. For example, I found that just by writing an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I usually always find the answer to my question while I write it. That's also why I don't always post questions these days.

But when you depend on something that does not even understand ***context***, then clearly, you'll end up having the wrong mindset more often than not to solve this by yourself. We all used/tried a search engine to find inspiration at least once for a problem, but this is worse than that because it doesn't have:

1. Accountability (yes, you can blame whoever trained/made it, but they'll end up blaming the dataset or the "AI" since as mentioned, it's just marketing noise).
2. Attribution: It doesn't even show you credit/attribute it to the original writer of whatever it's writing. Sure, if you believe that it's intelligent, it might make sense to think it just made that itself, but that's ***again***, not how this works.
   Everything in any GPT3 (and by extension, most "AI" tools) are just mutated input that was used when training it. It's technically more complex than that, but, when you get [result like this](https://twitter.com/docsparse/status/1581461734665367554?s=46&t=yF5zaMKk62GD32GddpVd2Q), you really start to notice a pattern here (this is for `copilot`, but it's also using gpt3 like chatgpt is, albeit differently, so the same apply here).

Don't even get me started on the plagiarism implication this brings, as that would be way out of scope for this post I think.

3. Understanding. As others pointed out, it often does not actually correctly state explanations for things. Excerpt [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f7UB.png), [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2GuU.png). I have more, but sadly there is a limit of character, so you get the idea. If someone has a problem because they don't know or understand how to do something, and are clueless, but totally hopeful that this "thing" will give them what they want, will totally become dependent on this, and as a result, become extremely surprised whenever it's wrong or someone else contradicts what's written there. It also does not [understand context](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/191197/is-it-ok-to-generate-parts-of-a-research-paper-using-a-large-language-model-such/191214?noredirect=1#comment516040_191214) even if the result might align with the input.

> Adopting the AI by the site has nothing to do with banning the use of AI to provide answers. These two policies can coexist.

Sadly, they cannot coexist, especially because you cannot trust that people will think logically when using this, and not trust it/try to understand it instead.

As I said in the comments, "AI" is just a term/word for marketing. The real term would be **Neural Network**, or more correctly [**Statistical Learning**](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/191197/is-it-ok-to-generate-parts-of-a-research-paper-using-a-large-language-model-such/191214?noredirect=1#comment516040_191214). [AI does not know, does not understand and is in no way intelligent, even if the result sometimes says otherwise](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/191214/165338).

That doesn't mean it's not useful, but the TLDR is: This doesn't align with the goal of SO/SE.

Comment: _If you have a problem and a "tool" gave you another set of problems_.. Ah.. the XY problem became X-AI problem

Comment: maybe X-WHY will work too, given as I mentioned, will lead to more people asking why this doesn't work and "btw this is from chatgpt :D"

Comment: @SurajRao: *...a "tool" gave you another set of problems...* I imagine a big box full of shoes and glass bottles...

Comment: "Worse case, they repost that as a question while mentioning they don't understand why the "AI" gave them a wrong answer." I have already seen this happening.

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that a some of ChatGPT's model comes from StackOverflow. When OpenAI updates their model post-2021, it's going to have to figure out how to filter out a lot of the incorrect information it generated.

Comment: You know, it is a hard question is phylosophy, that a being emulating intelligence is actually intelligent or not. Behind the question, there is a not admitted but somehow... *heard* "side question", do we have a soul. We can see this thing as a machine language processor capable to process the best google hit to an answer. We can see it as a living, thinking being. I am not a phylosopher, and I have (strong) beliefs in the matter, but I am not an expert. I can say, what do I feel. I feel *fear*. I feel *fear* that everything destructs what was the life and technology for me today.

Comment: @Aaron_H Probably people talking with him, will correct him. If it is an enough good AI, it will understand the believable proofs that he tought it badly, and it updates his model.

Comment: @peterh I know, and I at least agree that this is a complicated debate. It can be condensed to a simple Chinese room vs Turing test, but putting that aside, Once you know how it works (eg: statistical learning, etc) and even without taking into account the concept of soul/special human feature into account, you can at least tell there is nothing to fear, aside from what people do with them, rather than the "tool" themselves.

Comment: (cont2). I do agree that intelligence is a difficult concept to fully and entirely explain in details. What separate us from XYZ? I'm not an expert either, but I do believe it is in part the understanding of context. Statistical algorithm need to bruteforce using random trick such as learning rate and weights, and etc to even "grasp" the smallest of "pattern" that we understand, but we do not need to do that.

Comment: (cont 3) If someone goes back in time and show off a mini size computer, everyone would think it is "intelligent", but to most people, even people agreeing on the whole "AI is real" concept, would most likely not think of a single silicon chip as intelligent. But to people less used, and perhaps, not as knowledgeable on the matter, maybe.

Comment: (last cont) I said it [earlier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422013/chatgpt-should-be-incorporated-into-the-site/422019?noredirect=1#comment938334_422013) and I'll say it again, AI is just a hype and the real things it represents isn't what it tries to convey. It's fine if people still like to think or believe whatever they want, regardless if they know how things actually work or not. That still doesn't make their state any less truthful, though.

Comment: @NordineLotfi Considering the history, what do you think, what will people do with them?

Comment: @NordineLotfi Now AI can overthink the best chess players of the world. Next time AI will be able to overthink all the politicians of the world. We won't see about it anything, as we can not see any special in a chess game between two 3000+ ELO machines. They step, step, and once one of them mates. Not even the world chess champion would understand, why they stepped on this way. By analogy, we would see that so that one of the countries becomes suddenly surprisingly successful in the world politics, close to become a "world master".

Comment: @NordineLotfi Would you really want it? Would you really want it if it won't be the USA?

Comment: @NordineLotfi There is another thing. Your brain is a NN. It has about 100billion neutrons, about 50 synapses pro neuron and an about 20 tick/second top processing rate. It is not far from being emulatable by a table computer. Actually, a today supercomputer can do more. We could simulate a human brain long ago, we can not yet correctly train it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252886/discussion-between-nordine-lotfi-and-peterh).

Comment: Chinese room: the *[Chinese room argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room)*. *"a digital computer executing a program cannot have a "mind", "understanding", or "consciousness", regardless of how intelligently or human-like the program may make the computer behave."*

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what I meant in a comment here :) @PeterMortensen although I roughly agree with that, the way it is portrayed isn't how I would define it, but I guess it's better than the other side of the argument :/