# Is it true that moderator overreach is turning away a large number of users?

Tags: discussion, new-users, moderation

There is this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389583/671107) on meta that makes an announcement to the mods on some of the new requirements they will be needed to present before suspending a user who supposedly used AI to generate an answer. In that answer they state:

> Internal evidence strongly suggests that the **overapplication** of suspensions for AI-generated content may be **turning away** a large number of **legitimate contributors** to the site.

They have also criticized a **tool** that moderators use for tracing AI generated content for producing a high number of false positives. This means that a lot of innocent users might have been banned as a result of a false positive check. Is moderator overreach making the Stack Exchange experience bad both for users (they are turned away) and for the company (lost a legitimate number of visitors)?

Comment: Where is the hard data that backs up this assertion? The actual data, either from you or from the site owners?

Comment: Short answer: SE has no idea what they’re talking about.

Comment: What do you get from the comments under that post?

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship: I don't know that you can say that. All we can say with certainty is that the site owners are making this assertion but without backing it up, as yet.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, based on an internal evidence, they have something convincing but cant make the data public for some reason.

Comment: If you consider users that copy-paste from ChatGPT as legitimate contributors, then sure, they are turned away

Comment: @PassionateSE: something may be "convincing" to *you*, but I'm an  empiricist, and until I see real evidence, it doesn't convince me one bit.

Comment: I don’t think anybody here really believes that they have anything convincing. As a matter of fact, a great number of us are quite convinced they are actually lying.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship, they are right about the false positives tool though.

Comment: @PassionateSE But also, not really. They’re not much right. We have been aware of that for a long time. They are twisting the reality, and spreading misinformation and lies about the way we have been moderating AI content.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels They conducted an analysis, and the data from the analysis pushed them to make the policy effective. Companies do that all the time, they cannot wake up one day and decide anything without facts

Comment: The public messaging has been very different than private communication. The fact that there is this public/private split is infuriating on its own. The data hasn't been shared, the messaging is making implications without talking to any of us prior to this, and it's driving everyone to make inferences to data we can't see.

Comment: @PassionateSE For a number of years now, they have conducted analyses based on data that doesn’t tell the whole picture, or they read too much into it. They are constantly critcized for their analyses, and rightly so.

Comment: "*based on an internal evidence*" you might be right, but SE is also very secretive even to us mods. So... who knows? About the detectors, we all have known about their limitations since the beginning though.

Comment: @Andy, what about the over application of user suspension, are they right about that?

Comment: [Here’s our response to SE](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/)

Comment: The tool mentioned is a data point, but no moderator is depending only on a single tool we all know has a high false positive rate.

Comment: *"They have also criticized a tool that moderators use"* What *specific* tool are you talking about? The linked post just says that all current AI text detection programs have a high false positives rate. *The mods know that*, which is why they certainly do *not* rely on such tools, and some mods don't use them at all.

Comment: Bah, why are we re-hashing the same things over-and-over again in this needlessly redundant meta post?

Comment: @Andy, is a mod obligated to suspend a user if that user has posted content generated by AI, do they have no options such as warning or messaging that user?

Comment: We have been following the guidelines we worked with SE to develop and [put in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) which mentions the suspension of such users.

Comment: @Andy, but maybe they are worried that a large number of users are being turned away by the mods doing their job. This is very difficult for them, to find a balancing point between mods doing their job and also make sure a legitimate number of users are not sent away

Comment: @PassionateSE: [please see Machavity's post on this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424979/522444)

Comment: "high number of false positives" is completely arbitrary statement that was not backed by any data. Nobody is turning away legitimate contributors, The only thing we had in large numbers was utter crap AI generated posts.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, but why suspend the user, there is this reputation dissociation technique where the mods reverse all reputation gains made by the user from the AI generated content and an answer ban, aren't those enough punishment?

Comment: @PassionateSE: severity of punishment should fit the severity of the alleged crime, and most feel that using AI generation and passing the information off as your own constitutes this, and so a first violation had been the above and a 1 week suspension, with I believe higher degrees of punishment for repeated offences.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, why is it a major concern to SE that users are being turned away, I mean this already exists via the downvotes and closing of new posts?

Comment: @PassionateSE no, mods cannot reverse reputation gains, only SE employees can do that. As for the rest, we could indeed have stopped suspending, at least for a while, and we would have if that had been what the company requested. But it isn't. Instead, they came down on us like a ton of bricks, and require us to ignore the consensus of our own communities. This is why we're angry.

Comment: @terdon, when you suggest the mods could have stopped suspending for a while, are you validating the company's claim that a legitimate number of users have been turned away?

Comment: @PassionateSE **It's *not physically possible***. Look at the numbers. Moderators *can't* suspend enough people to have the impact that SE has claimed the suspensions are causing, unless we were programmatically suspending *everybody*, which we weren't doing. SE's problems are that traffic is leaving in *millions*. SE moderators suspend *thousands*. The effects are *off by orders of magnitude*.

Comment: @Makyen, if traffic is leaving in millions. This is a serious issue for the company. I also don't think mods suspend that large number of users every day. This has got to be from competition by chat GPT.

Comment: It's not *just* ChatGPT, but ChatGPT is a major contributor to making an already negative trend dramatically worse. I, of course, don't have *actual* information as to why people are leaving, but leaving for ChatGPT and other AI generation providers is the most likely thing, IMO. [Here's a blog post on similarweb showing traffic on ChatGPT, SO, and GitHub](//www.similarweb.com/amp/blog/insights/ai-news/stack-overflow-chatgpt/). Question and answer asking/answering rates are explored in [answer to: "Did Stack Exchange's traffic go down since ChatGPT?"](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/387302/271271)

Comment: @Makyen, yes Github also launched their own Q and A with admins for the libraries involved like opencv and the rest

Comment: @PassionateSE no, I am not validating the company's knee-jerk reaction which is based on no data at all (they haven't been able to show us even one single wrong suspension!). I am just saying that if the company had just told us "we are afraid there may be many unfair suspensions, could you stop suspending for a while" or "could you warn before suspending", I'm sure all mods would have been happy to comply. They could have talked to us. Instead, they chose to attack us.

Comment: *"Is it true that moderator overreach is turning away a large number of users"* - Just as true as that there are a lot of people who post junk that needs to be turned away. Question is: what does the company *really* want? Quality content... or more traffic? It's starting to look like quality is only a thing on paper.

Comment: Aggressive downvotes and close votes have *always* turned users away from this site. (Source: ask your co-workers whether or not they use this site and why.) But sure, let's blame AI.

Comment: Thanks to SE for doing this, how would we have known they value all users if they hadn't passed this communication to us? Every user matters, question banned and answer banned equally. I can now contribute to the site knowing that SE cares about me.

Comment: Traffic to Stackoverflow is down, that's for sure - decrease in post by 25% over the last 6 months, https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.07367, thereby hastening a historical trend of decreased traffic. Explanation surely is that user now find answers faster via ChatGPT. Moderator overreach and aggressive downvotes and close votes may partly play a role in this in the sense that ChatGPT is always friendly and helpful, whereas SO for many comes across as an extremely hostile platform...

Comment: @TomWenseleers, yeap and that's why am content with GPT. A good post always gets zero downvotes and the upvoting is biased

Comment: @VibrantWaves 50% drop in traffic to Stackoverflow over the past 1.5 years in fact, with drop in traffic over the last half a year, since the introduction of ChatGPT, being especially striking: https://observablehq.com/@ayhanfuat/the-fall-of-stack-overflow

Comment: @TomWenseleers,  yeap GPT emerged and lured away a significant number of StackOverflow users

Answer (score 57):

There is no hard evidence on there being a significant amount of inappropriately handed suspensions due to the "no AI generated content" policy. The company handwaved those ideas based on a vague assortment of cues. Even without being a moderator, one can grasp this conclusion from the following points:

- The official announcement from the company pointed towards the inaccuracy of *one of the generated content detection tools* as a justification for this measure. This is a distraction and an attempt of poisoning discussion, as moderators are known to use much more than one of the tools at their disposal. Some moderators have never used any of these detectors, while others that do consult a detector have never relied *solely* on its results. Therefore, in no way does the detection performance of a single tool reflect the moderators' overall capacity at identifying this form of activity.
- It would be unsurprising if the company had been collecting complaints from people who were suspended for this reason. Aside from the fact that each complaint needs to be evaluated carefully rather than just taking their word for it, they constitute anecdotic evidence at best, and not proof that there is a systemic moderation failure.
- The idea that "legitimate users" are being pushed away from the site is worth breaking down. Complaints like this will often conflate the various things about the platform that they don't like, including how voting and closing works. This is irrespective of how "legitimate" people think they are, and even before AI generated posts were a problem, this was never an excuse to stop voting, closing questions, or moderating altogether. But much worse than that, one has to be blunt here: the activity of users just building up dubious content derived from ChatGPT or other AI text generation tools is simply **not legitimate**. Let's not call them as such.

Ever since Stack Overflow became widely popular, moderators had to resort to heavy handed actions against the flow of low quality content. As these tools opened up yet another vector for problematic content, moderation had to adapt just the same. Unfortunately, the company is out of touch with the community, and wants to optimize for more participation rather than more quality. Emptying the hands of moderators with respect to AI generated content is a case of throwing the baby with the bath water, the full consequences of which may take time to sense in its entirety. Folks will continue raising their fists against something they don't like, but the difference is that, after some time, it may no longer be worth scavenging for answers here. We shrug and wave goodbye.

Comment: This turf between the mods and the company is an interesting one and am gonna stay tuned on new developments as the mods have already threatened a strike which will let poor quality posts flood the site, what if the company says its okay for the mods to strike, we have AI that can detect and close poor quality posts?

Comment: @PassionateSE I think what you see as a turf between the mods and the company is merely a tip of the iceberg. It's indeed between the company and folks like me who rely on Stack Overflow in their programming jobs. I use Stack Overflow almost daily and I don't want my search results to be polluted by unverified output from ChatGPT parroted by folks having no slightest idea of the subject matter. I use SO to learn from experienced programmers who understand what they post - if it can't give me that then I will go somewhere else

Comment: @gnat, what if they implement AI into the system to replace the mods?

Comment: @PassionateSE why speculate about things that aren't happening. _After_ they implement that system and _after_ such system was tested and proven to work well enough, I probably would be interested. Meanwhile, this is not even close, so I simply refuse to waste my brain energy on talking about fictional things

Comment: @gnat, yes the AI could generate an answer that is outdated or misleading because the cut off date for the data GPT uses is 2021. The company should just let the mods do their job irrespective of losing a legitimate number of users.

Comment: @PassionateSE of AI were capable of replacing mods, that would mean that AI detectors work well enough to reliably recognize AI content, which they don't. It would also mean AI would be good enough that we wouldn't need to guard against it, it would be accurate enough to be consistently helpful. In any case, if that's what the company wants to do, let them. That would mean I, at least, would have no interest in participating on these sites any more anyway.

Comment: By the way, the reason chatGPT gets things wrong isn't the cutoff date, it's that it is just a large language model and those things get stuff wrong. The cutoff is a small, tiny part of it.

Comment: @PassionateSE What's the point of SE if it's just a big cache of stale LLM answers? If you want an LLM answer, ask an LLM. If you want a human answer, ask SE. Everyone is happy. The company allowing LLM answers pretty much defeats their entire value proposition as a business, even if LLM technology can magically stop hallucinations in the near future. Until then, it's just polluting the site with trash and making it even harder to curate than it was before LLMs.

Comment: @gnat-onstrike- Is there somewhere else to go (on the internet)? Or is it time to launch a new platform (with a non-profit structure of course)?

Comment: @Joooeey sure, one example list of alternatives is [discussed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/165773)

Answer (score 36):

There is no evidence for this claim. It's possible but doubtful.

SE hasn't provided any data to support this statement. We have only the data that can be officially gathered (either from SEDE or from the 25k mod tools). The analytics tell us something, but it doesn't tell us the cause. Let me present publicly available information so anyone can draw conclusions.

Since November 2022 participation on Stack Overflow has dramatically decreased. The number of questions asked (and in turn the number of new answers) has almost halved in the past 6 months.

- The number of all new posts: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1758280/2137011#graph
- The number of all new questions: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1758280/2137016#graph
- The number of all new answers: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1758280/2137019#graph

Taking the week commencing 2022-11-28 (the week ChatGPT 3 was released) as the base, we can calculate the percentage.

- All posts: from 85236 to 48492 (56% of what it was in Nov 2022)
- Questions: from 45554 to 26424 (58% of what it was in Nov 2022)
- Answers: from 39682 to 22068 (55% of what it was in Nov 2022)

Please note that all numbers include the deleted posts.

The decline in participation is gradual, and the trend shows that it will keep going down in the coming months. There is a smaller but also significant decrease in the number of votes: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1758300/2137026#graph. The number of accept votes has also halved in the last 6 months https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1758300/2137028#graph which corresponds to the decline in the questions asked.

The 25k analytics tool shows that the number of total visits has decreased by 33% percent in the last 6 months, although it doesn't follow the same pattern as the decline in new posts. There were drastic drops in the number of page views in January and in April.

In terms of suspensions, there was a major increase in the number of suspensions across the network since December 2022 (according to the information received in chat from staff, but also observed by SO mods), but for the exact data you need to wait for SE to release something. How the number of suspensions correlates to the number of active participants that decided to stop contributing to Stack Overflow is unclear.

Comment: wondering if there is any publicly (for moderators) available data of suspensions due to ai answers and those answers to run whatever tool/analysis to detect the alleged false positives _in that subsample_? Or is already that tool/analysis used by the company a secret?

Comment: I doubt it. The tools we have are so bad we can't even look up the suspensions or past messages. I assume staff uses just the internal version of SEDE.

Comment: The company should have asked the mods to stop suspending for a while

Comment: @PassionateSE That's something we've mentioned to them many times. Our returning to the normal of sending a warning upon first occurrence, rather than a suspension (they *encouraged* suspension on first occurrence), would have taken only a single chat message like "Hey y'all, for AI generated content, please return to warning prior to suspending.". That's all it would have taken. No need to formally change policy. No drama. Easy. It would have also provided data that would falsify their assertion that the suspensions are dramatically impacting their engagement across the platform.

Comment: @Makyen, people are gonna start by asking GPT something and only when GPT fails to provide a solution then they post to Stack Exchange. That could explain why the new posts are going down. People give GPT first priority for their questions.

Comment: @Makyen, it's up to Stack Exchange to up their game by improving the site to include a separate chat bot called Meta Chat bot for each platform and use data available in the network to train it, it's not too late for Stack Exchange. They can do this even if Google failed at Bard. They can then implement HTML blink to animate the response

Comment: @Makyen, SE can implement a chat bot that accepts a question then looks up for similar questions on the related site and finds the most upvoted or accepted answer for that question and then replies to a user like chat GPT but included the author of that post in the response

Comment: @PassionateSE While any or all of those might be a good idea, it is ineffective to post the ideas as comments here or ping me for them. I have almost no say in what SE does. I can make suggestions in [tag:feature-requests] on meta sites, which is something anyone else can do. For moderator related things, I do have a bit of a back-channel which can be used for moderator related issues, but it's not effective at major changes.

Comment: Even issues which are critical for the tool to be useful I've had to report 3 or 4 times and wait a year and a half for resolution ([example](/a/360067/271271); first reported about a year and a half prior to that post). Other things, even just simply changing *just text* have taken multiple years from when others have reported them. If you want to suggest something, then you need to post a [tag:feature-request] question.

Answer (score -16):

Yes, but it is a phenomenon that predates the use of ChatGPT. ChatGPT is merely a catalyst used to rein in moderation abuse.

Comment: Could be right, some mods abuse the system but a majority of them go by the book. Some users might feel oppressed but they are actually maintaining the integrity and quality of the site by being tough.

Comment: It is the contrary. With the most active SO moderators on strike, I would not dare to participate regularly with comments and whatnot, and then have to be subjected to abuse for several hours until a moderator comes along. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396581 My experience here on Meta tells me that being against moderators in general is an awfully bad stance to have.