# Users in the non-AI "write title during review" group of the title drafting experiment have an empty and non-interactive duplicate suggestions section

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, asking-questions, ask-question-wizard

The duplicate suggestions section is inaccessible and invariably empty for users in the 'write title during review' test group of the [title-drafting experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424638/11107541). It is disabled and cannot be reached. The only thing that can be done is to click the "Review your Question" button:

[image: Ask question wizard with duplicate suggestions greyed out]

Yes, I know this only affects questions from the Ask Wizard, but that's still *a lot* of questions that we'll be getting in the next few days. Can you please fix this? I assume that the duplicate suggestions phase should be moved to go after the title input?

I am in the experiment group with no AI suggestions. Please also check if this bug is present for those with AI title suggestions.